# Unable to submit form using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, countdown

So the scenario is on my page I have a form along with a countdown timer. If the countdown timer reaches 0:00 I have a statement which activates and is supposed to submit the form as it stands.

here is that statement:

```
if (Todays_Date >= Target_Date) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        $('#testForm').submit();
        alert("Timeup, Submitting exam....");
        return;
    }
```

what actually happens is, it fires, the timer stops (cleared timeout) and alert pops up. However the form does not submit and take the user to the action page.

I have copied all of the code into this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Cnvc/20/) to layout the basic principle.

the time of which countdown is targetted to is passed in the HTML at the bottom. you'll see the countdown() call.

I really am in a pickle and would appreciate someones help.

**note**: I know this is not a secure method etc.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have form element called `submit`:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Complete Test">
```

Change its name so something like:

```
<input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Complete Test" />
```

And your code will work.

When the form contains element called `submit`, referring to `formElement.submit` will refer the element instead of the actual `submit` method - this is very common problem.

Comment: Cheers @buymypi (:-D) the trick is to alert the value of `submit` and in your case, it showed it as input element.

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
$("#testForm").trigger('submit');
```

The way you went with is binding the submit event to a function, which means once submit occurs, something you specify in the function (that you don't have) will happen.

Comment: If you'll view the jQuery source code you'll see that calling `.submit()` is calling this exact code as well. :)